# How to get a flag from an Arduino button through serial communication?

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

My objective is to obtain a flag that is sent from the Arduino by a button. This flag is going to be sent through serial communication to a C# windows form program where i will be able to obtain the flag.

The data sent to the serial port by the Arduino is "ON" and "OFF", "ON" when the button is clicked and "OFF" when the button is not clicked. This flag will be used to turn on and off the red chart that will be displayed in the windows form.

My problem is how do i get this "ON" and "OFF" from the serial communication keeping in mind that data from the sensors are also being sent to the windows form application.

```
//C# Code

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using rtChart;

namespace Distance_Sensor_using_Flight_of_time
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string recvData = "temporary";
        bool breakloop = false;
        kayChart chartData;
        bool buttonPress = false;
        string bufferString = "";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //chart1.Series.Add("Series1");
            //Connection COM & Baud Rate
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            string[] rates = new string[10] { "300", "600", "1200", "2400", "9600", "14400", "19200", "38400", "57600", "115200" };
            cboBaudRate.SelectedText = "9600";
            cboCOM.Items.AddRange(ports);
            cboBaudRate.Items.AddRange(rates);
            if (ports.Length >= 1)
                cboCOM.SelectedIndex = 0;

            //kayChart real time
            chartData = new kayChart(chart1, 60);

            btnStart.Enabled = false;
            btnSave.Enabled = false;
            chart1.Series["Series1"].Enabled = false;
        }

        private void BtnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (btnConnect.Text == "Disconnect")
                {
                    if (btnStart.Text == "Stop")
                        MessageBox.Show("Please click \"Stop\" button first!");
                    else
                    {
                        serialPort1.Close();
                        btnStart.Enabled = false;
                        btnConnect.Text = "Connect";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    serialPort1.PortName = cboCOM.Text;
                    serialPort1.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(cboBaudRate.Text);
                    serialPort1.Parity = Parity.None;
                    serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                    serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
                    serialPort1.Open();

                    btnStart.Enabled = true;
                    btnConnect.Text = "Disconnect";
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void serialDataReceive(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!breakloop)
            {
                SerialPort sData = sender as SerialPort;
                recvData = sData.ReadLine();

                bufferString = recvData;
                //rtbData.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {rtbData.AppendText(recvData); });

                //update chart
                if (recvData == "ON\r" || recvData == "OFF\r")
                {
                    if (recvData == "ON")
                        buttonPress = true;
                    else
                        buttonPress = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    double data;
                    bool result = Double.TryParse(recvData, out data);
                    if (result)
                    {
                        chartData.TriggeredUpdate(data);
                        if (buttonPress == false)
                        {
                            chart1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { chart1.Series["Series1"].Enabled = false; });
                            chartData.serieName = "Length";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            chart1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { chart1.Series["Series1"].Enabled = true; });
                            chartData.serieName = "Series1";
                        }
                    }
                }
                rtbData.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { rtbData.AppendText(recvData); });
            }
        }

        private void BtnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (btnStart.Text == "Start")
                {
                    serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialDataReceive);
                    btnStart.Text = "Stop";
                    breakloop = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    btnStart.Text = "Start";
                    breakloop = true;
                    //serialPort1.DataReceived += null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                btnStart.Text = "Start";
            }
        }

        private void RtbData_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rtbData.SelectionStart = rtbData.Text.Length;
            rtbData.ScrollToCaret();
        }        
    }
}
```

```
//Arduino Code

/* This example shows how to get single-shot range
 measurements from the VL53L0X. The sensor can optionally be
 configured with different ranging profiles, as described in
 the VL53L0X API user manual, to get better performance for
 a certain application. This code is based on the four
 "SingleRanging" examples in the VL53L0X API.

 The range readings are in units of mm. */

#include <Wire.h>
#include <VL53L0X.h>

VL53L0X sensor;


// Uncomment this line to use long range mode. This
// increases the sensitivity of the sensor and extends its
// potential range, but increases the likelihood of getting
// an inaccurate reading because of reflections from objects
// other than the intended target. It works best in dark
// conditions.

//#define LONG_RANGE


// Uncomment ONE of these two lines to get
// - higher speed at the cost of lower accuracy OR
// - higher accuracy at the cost of lower speed

//#define HIGH_SPEED
#define HIGH_ACCURACY

const int buttonPin = 2;
const int ledPin = 8;
int buttonState = 0;
bool inLoop = false;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();

  // initialize the LED pin as an output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  // initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);

  sensor.init();
  sensor.setTimeout(500);

#if defined LONG_RANGE
  // lower the return signal rate limit (default is 0.25 MCPS)
  sensor.setSignalRateLimit(0.1);
  // increase laser pulse periods (defaults are 14 and 10 PCLKs)
  sensor.setVcselPulsePeriod(VL53L0X::VcselPeriodPreRange, 18);
  sensor.setVcselPulsePeriod(VL53L0X::VcselPeriodFinalRange, 14);
#endif

#if defined HIGH_SPEED
  // reduce timing budget to 20 ms (default is about 33 ms)
  sensor.setMeasurementTimingBudget(20000);
#elif defined HIGH_ACCURACY
  // increase timing budget to 200 ms
  sensor.setMeasurementTimingBudget(200000);
  //sensor.setMeasurementTimingBudget(900000);
#endif
}

void loop()
{
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  Serial.print(sensor.readRangeSingleMillimeters());
  if (sensor.timeoutOccurred()) { Serial.print(" TIMEOUT"); }

  Serial.println();

  if (buttonState == HIGH && inLoop == false)
  {
    Serial.write("ON");
    Serial.println();
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    inLoop = true;
  }
  else if (buttonState == LOW && inLoop == true)
  {
    Serial.write("OFF");
    Serial.println();
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    inLoop = false;
  }
}
```

I expect that the chart will turn red once the button is clicked and blue when the button is not clicked. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Get a good communication book at read!!!.  The client is the master and the server (device) is the slave.  So usually the client will send a commands and the server will respond back. Some cases the slave may be in a continuous mode and send status.You have two layers of the network (network has 7 layer) 1) The transport layer which is the serial port 2) Application layer which are the messages. You need to add to the messages to indicate the type of message as well as the data.The sensor data should indicate that it is the sensor and the sensor number. Button should contain the button number.

Comment: It appears that you are close, could you provide a bit more description about what it is doing wrong or what is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although what you are doing may work (ie just trying to figure out what the message is on the receive side),  it is far more scale-able if you use some form of message header and a delimiter.  So your messages would look like this:

"btnState,true"

"btnState,false"

"data,124"

On the receive side, you will need to do a recvData.Split(',') and then check the first member of the array to find out what they message type is and then parse the second part accordingly.

Also, relating to your code specifically, I am unsure why you chose to use Serial.write for you "ON" and "OFF" instead of sticking to Serial.println.  I am not positive without testing, but pretty sure you are trying to use the println as a message delimiter, and I think it may be sending the write and the empty println as two separate messages (which would explain why your on off equality may fail).

Comment: That may be a good idea, will try it soon. My problem currently is that even if "ON" or "OFF" is detected, the program will not enter the if statement.

If possible, I would also like to know a better way to debug my current project... since the data sent to my application is every 200ms it will be hard for me to get when the arduino sends an "ON" or "OFF" button and thus i cannot debug because it will take time for the "ON" or "OFF" signal to come.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could look into wireshark or really any serial sniffer.  That would give you a historical record of all serial coms.  If it is not entering the if statement though, it sounds like ON and OFF are not being detected... have you tried doing some debug prints inside those conditionals to make sure that they are being triggered at all?

Comment: I have successfully managed to get the flag into my program with the solution of Sneaky Polar Bear. Thank you all in advance and special thanks to Sneaky Polar Bear for giving me a good alternative.